# How do i alter the step for time input for IOS?

Tags: ios, html

I want to have a time input using html5 in ios. I have tried using the step="900" attribute to allow only intervals of 15 minutes, which works when running it in the browser, but not on my ipad which is what im developing for.

```
<input type="time" id="deliveryTime" value="09:00:00"  step="900">
```

However in IOS this still displays every minute 00-59.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you solved that ?? how to do "step" ?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, iOS Safari does not support the `min`, `max`, or `step` attributes for `time` input fields.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

For some reason iOS Chrome is not mentioned on caniuse.com but it does not handle "step" either.

Comment: iOS Chrome is actually Safari in a Chrome Design.